# CakePHP - Saving data in multiple tables

Tags: cakephp

My site's structure is like this:

1 `User` hasOne `UserAccount`, with `user_id` as foreign key.

2 `UserAccount` hasOne `PrivateProfile`, with `user_account_id` as foreign key.

3 `UserAccount` hasMany `StudyProfiles`, with `user_account_id` as foreign key.

4 `UserAccount` hasMany `LanguageProfiles`, with `user_account_id` as foreign key.

At first, I create a `User` entry to the database along with `UserAccount`, through `saveAssociated()` and the correspondent form. Everything's ok, I've got both entries created in my database.

But then I want to add some info like a `PrivateProfile` and a couple of `LanguageProfiles`, again through a form. I've created a function inside `UserAccountsController` with:

```
 public function new_personal() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            unset($this->UserAccount->PrivateProfile->validate['user_account_id']);
            $this->UserAccount->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error'));
    }
}
```

I suppose that I'm doing something wrong, because these new entries are not being created. Someone could give me a clue? Thanks!

Comment: Usually these kinds of problems come from the array of data you're trying to save is not formatted correctly.  I'd `debug($this->request->data)` to see how the data looks.  If you can't see something obviously wrong, try putting in some data for a UserAccount with a PrivateProfile into your database manually, and then see how CakePHP formats that data when you get it with a `$this->UserAccount->find('first', array('conditions' => array('UserAccount.id' => id of the UserAccount)));`  Also, is the line with PersonalProfile instead of PrivateProfile in your code a mistake?

Comment: You should also try `debug($this->UserAccount->validationErrors)` after your call to saveAll, to see if that turns up anything.

Comment: This is what I get: `debug($this->request->data): array(
 'PrivateProfile' => array(
  'name' => 'Name',
  'last_name' => 'Last Name',
  'birth_date' => array(
   'day' => '19',
   'month' => '12',
   'year' => '1985'
  )
 )
)`, `debug($this->UserAccount->validationErrors): array()`. I haven't tried putting data manually yet. What do you think?